# Browser inspector shows ::before pseudo element is set to display: inline when it is block

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools, pseudo-element

I'm seeing this weird error on both Chrome and Firefox.

The width and height properties are disabled because Chrome says: "The display: inline property prevents height from having an effect. Try setting display to something other than inline."

But the property below it says display:block.

[image: CSS error]

Firefox has a similar message.

I don't know what else I can do.

CSS code:

```
.test:before {
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 3rem;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -3.5rem;
    font-size: 3rem;
    background-image: url("image.jpg"); /* this image doesn't display */
}
```

Comment: It's really hard to diagnose a CSS issue without any CSS code. All you have provided is a picture of your dev tools. Please put a code snippet in your question that can reproduce the issue

Comment: `display:block` should  happen BEFORE the height/width are set ..    That said, you could be being overwritten by another class .. To test this theory, use `display:block !important;`

Comment: FWIW I have seen some errors with the inspector helper tooltips so if everything is working correctly I wouldn’t stress about it. However, if it’s not working as expected you’ll need to post a code example so folks can help https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Zak The order of CSS properties has no effect in this case. That matters when you have the same property twice, in which case the second one is applied.

Comment: @Zak The order didn't change anything, and the !important didn't either.

Comment: Try adding `content: ''`

Comment: Or maybe adding `content: ''` to the pseudo element might work.

Comment: @Fynn This worked (made my background image show up)! Not sure why the inspector is showing this error. I couldn't reproduce it in jsfiddle anyway.

Comment: I can reproduce the rendering behavior in [the MDN playground](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before#try_it). Setting just `display: block` on the `::before` doesn't cause the lines to break, but adding `content: ''` fixes it.

Comment: This question was more regarding the inspector tooltip text. I didn't care so much about what I was trying to do with CSS. It seems it is just a bug in chrome that also happens to appear in firefox, but is triggered by something specific to the site I was working on.